# Insert data into multiple tables via 1 form on Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to be able to insert data into multiple Tables (artists, songs, albums, genres). I also have relational tables (artistsongs, albumsongs, songgenres) that contain the ID of the relevant table (eg. Artistsongs = Artistid, songid).

How do I go about creating a trigger/sequence/function/package to get the data from a form into the relevant tables automatically and so they all link up correctly.

Apologies about the Vagueness however I am stumped as to know where to start.

I am using Oracle XE as the Database, with Oracle Application Express as the front End application.

Any answers would be extremely Helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to start out using the Create Page wizard to create Master/Detail pages. If you are new to Application Express you might want to just build a few of these to get an idea of how they work. Another good option is the page type Form with Report.

Once you see how a report links to a page with a form you can then try to combine some of the links on one report. I can see you might want to have a report for artists where one link takes you to their songs and another to their albums. The albums report might take you to another report of songs. And each of these might also link to a table for editing.

If you want to show all your tables in one page and have them all editable this is not trivial and I don't know where to point you to start out.